# Detect modifications occured In DB and update my Grid

Tags: c#, database, datagrid

I have created a program that shows the content of my table into a `<DataGrid>`.
So far, I used an `ObservableCollection` which contains the result of my `Select` database query. What I want to achieve is when a person modify or add a new entry into the Table, I want to automatically detect that and rerun a select query and show the new content in the data grid.

How could I do that? Keywords please or links.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you using an ORM like NHibernate or EntityFramework ?

Comment: @Antry : sorry i am new to all the .Net world :) I used WCF for retreiving result and WPF to invoke the method. So I m sure no Hiberbate but do'nt know about EF. (I try o follow the MVVM)

Comment: It's not something you'd do without knowing, so I guess you're not using either ^^, look into the 'repository pattern' and the 'unit of work'

Comment: @Antry : Nothing

Comment: If the modification is made by your implementation, you can always do an event to fetch the data again, but if you want it to get triggered if you modify something in DB (even hard coded by hand) I don't think that it's possible, or I don't know of any related solution

Comment: @Antry : in fact I wanna the second scenario you said: If something modified the DB like changing manually the content of my Table (not via the App). 

`SqlNotificationRequest` couldn't help ? I thonk I have to do a call in a Timer too.

Comment: Actually, it does seem to be capable of fulfilling what you want, I have zero experience with it though, so I can't help you with that, I've only got a couple years of after-study experience, and haven't tackled this problem in the same way you are trying to; I'm afraid I won't be able to help you much more :s

Comment: @Antry : no problem thank you :)

Comment: Are you trying to update the view for the person who modified/added a new entry, or other clients ?

Comment: @Antry : updating the view for the clients to show modification done by a peron X via another application Like C++ app or ant other apps.

Comment: Oh, so you want a 'push-notification' like system but for SQL ?

Comment: @Antry : yup and for Oracle :) So i guess it makes it more limited as solution.

Comment: This seems relevant, but at this point I'm really just doing research with you and I don't have solutions; https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/B14251_01/adfns_dcn.htm